# Translation manager package for laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I installed **Translation manager** package , but i have a problem that when I try to access **/translations** it redirects me to my home page. I know the problem is that I don't use Laravel Authentication system I use a custom login with **Session**.

My question is **how can i modify translation manager settings to be compatible with my custom login ?**.

This is the login function that i use.

```
public function login(Request $request){
    $users = User::all();
    foreach($users as $user){
        if($user->email == $request->input('email') and Hash::check( $request->input('password') ,$user->password)){
            session_name('admin');
            session_start();
            $messages = Message::all();
            $_SESSION['user']=$user;
            $_SESSION['messages']=$messages;
            return redirect('/admin/Dashboard');
        }
    }
    return  back()->withErrors('Wrong credintials');
}
```